# How to add CSRF token to Angular 8 post request from Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, angular, csrf

I have an application with Django backend and angular frontend.
Now, these are connected with each other, I can get data from Django and show in Angular. As well Send a post request to Django.

But the issue is with CSRF token in Django. I disable the CSRF middleware in Django and the request process completely, but I know this is insecure.

Method to do a post request.

```
loadQuestion(id): Observable<any> {
    const body = {'choice': 'teseted with post method'};
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + id + '/vote', {headers: this.header, withCredentials: true, });
  }
```

I did some changes according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43365939/9246297).

`HttpClientXsrfModule.withConfig({ cookieName: 'csrftoken', headerName: 'X-CSRFToken' })`

but I get this error.

> app.module.ts:26 Uncaught TypeError: _angular_common_http__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.HttpClientXsrfModule.withConfig is not a function

So I changed it based on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492337/9246297)

`HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({ cookieName: 'csrftoken', headerName: 'X-CSRFToken' })`

This is my Django function to return data, as I said when I disabled CSRF middleware is working fine So I should fix the CSRF issue and passing it with Angular request.

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=4)
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return HttpResponse("You didn't select a choice.")
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponse(request)
```

Middleware code that I commented:

`'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`

and the error is `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

**Update**

I use the CORS Origin, here is my Django config

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
    'X-CSRFToken',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    'XSRF-TOKEN',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
    'csrftoken',
    'X-CSRF'
)

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: Is angular application served on the same domain as Django? If no, then you really don't need csrf, you can just check origin (which will be always present on cross-origin requests).

Comment: Angular is on `http://localhost:4200/` ang Django is on `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: @GwynBleidD I using Cross-Origin, I updated the question please check again.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your view with `csrf_exempt`

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def vote():
...
```

"If you’re using AngularJS 1.1.3 and newer, it’s sufficient to configure the $http provider with the cookie and header names:"

```
httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

Comment: Where should I put the second codes that you mentioned?

Comment: I use angular 8

Answer (score 0):

So I use this library called `ngx-cookie`, [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie) for it.
Install it & then add this in you service.ts.

```
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie';

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _cookieService: CookieService) {
  let csrf = this._cookieService.get("csrftoken");
  if (typeof(csrf) === 'undefined') {
    csrf = '';
  }
  this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'X-CSRFToken': csrf}),
  };
}

public postCall(payload){
  return this.http.post('/yourapi/', payload, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Explaination:

```
let csrf = this._cookieService.get("csrftoken");
```

this line is getting the csrf token from the cookie

```
 headers: new HttpHeaders({'X-CSRFToken': csrf}),
```

this line adds that value of csrf into the HttpHeaders.

```
this.http.post('/yourapi/', payload, this.httpOptions);
```

while making the post call we're using these headers

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in Angular 15 and Django 4.0 now can fetch csrf-token. Here is solution (is working):

1. In services file add function

```
authorizeUser(username: string, password: string, csrfmiddlewaretoken: string): Observable<any>{
  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/'
  const encodedBody = new URLSearchParams();
  encodedBody.set('username', username);
  encodedBody.set('password', password);
  encodedBody.set('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrfmiddlewaretoken)

  return this.http.post(url, encodedBody);

}
```

2. Add component AdminComponent

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit, HttpInterceptor {
  xsrf: string   = <string>this.cookieExtractor.getToken()

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    }
  );
  submitted = false
```

3. Add in previous component this important function

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      headers:  new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': this.xsrf }),
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

So the main problem which I have faced with writing application on both frontend and backend service that content-type must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not `application/json` (you can check via Postman sending request in Django-admin area). Hope that this solution will help you!

Comment: + CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True on backend side + delete , 'Cookie': this.xsrf  in frontend as cookie no need to add.